# MySQL/PHP - Nested Select Issue - Need To Obtain Values From Both Tables

Tags: php, sql

I just need help refining this script to give me the values from both tables joined on the ID.

Basically I want the ID from both tables and then be able to get the other values from both tables based on the IDs (if need be) and display them in a loop.

The code I have is below but won't work.

```
$select = myQ("SELECT * FROM users a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `videos` b WHERE a.id = b.id GROUP BY b.id HAVING count(*) > 1) ");    

$i=0;
while ($row = myF($select)) {
    $resultsLoopArray[$i]["videos.id"] = $row["id"];
    $resultsLoopArray[$i]["videos.vid"] = $row["vid"];
    $resultsLoopArray[$i]["users.username"] = $row["username"];             
    $i++;
}
if (isset($resultsLoopArray)) {
    $tpl->Loop("searchResultsLoop", $resultsLoopArray);
}
```

For now all I need is the username from the users table, the id and video id from the video table.

Can someone help by chance?

Comment: Please provide the data structures of the tables, and the sample data and expected outputs that you need so we can help.. Unfortunately, there's not much to go on from the info you've posted up to this point...

Comment: if you don't show us your db schema, we can't really help you further.

Answer (score 0):

you question is bit confusing me..
As for my understanding I am posting this soultion..

If you have two tables users , videos then .

```
$sql = "SELECT users.username , videos.* from users, videos where users.user_id = videos.user_id";
```

this query will fetch all record from users and videos table where user id is present in videos tables ...

Comment: Again, Naseer, thank you so much! that works perfectly! You've saved the day.